# JQuery within a partial view not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a view that has some jQuery to load a partial view (via a button click) into a div in the view. This works without a problem. However within the partial view I have a very similar bit of jQuery that will load another partial view into a div in the first partial view, but this isn't working, it almost seems like the jQuery in the first partial view isn't being loaded.

I have tried searching for solutions, but I haven't managed to find an answer. I have also re-created the jQuery function in a `@Ajax.ActionLink` which works fine, however I am trying to avoid the Microsoft helpers as I am trying to learn jQuery.

Here is the first partial view which contains the jQuery that doesn't seem to work, it also contains the `@Ajax.ActionLink` that does work:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.AddressIndexViewModel

<script>
    $(".viewContacts").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CustomerAddressContacts", "Customer")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { addressID: $(this).attr('data-addressid') },
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#customerAddressContactsPartial-" + $(this).attr('data-addressid'))
                        .html(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
<table class="customers" style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 25%">
            Name
        </th>
        <th style="width: 25%">
            Actions
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
    @foreach (Address item in Model.Addresses)
    {
    <table style="width: 100%; border-top: none">
        <tr id="address-id-@item.AddressID">
            <td style="width: 25%; border-top: none">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td style="width: 25%; border-top: none">
                <a href="#" class="viewContacts standardbutton" data-addressid="@item.AddressID">ContactsJQ</a>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Contacts", "CustomerAddressContacts", "Customer",
                    new { addressID = item.AddressID },
                    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "customerAddressContactsPartial-" + @item.AddressID, HttpMethod = "POST" },
                    new { @class = "standardbutton"})
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="customerAddressContactsPartial-@item.AddressID"></div>
    }
```

If someone could explain what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it then I would be very grateful.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have also re-created the jQuery function in a @Ajax.ActionLink
>   which works fine, however I am trying to avoid the Microsoft helpers
>   as I am trying to learn jQuery.

In case you didn't know, in ASP.NET MVC 3, Ajax.* helper use jQuery, contrary to ASP.NET MVC 2 where they were using Microsoft Ajax scripts. Also it is considered bad practice to put javascript code in your views and partial views.

I would recommend you externalizing this in a separate javascript file inside a function.

```
function ajaxifyViewContactsLink() {
    $('.viewContacts').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            context: this,
            success: function (result) {
                // see the updated markup of the partial below
                // that works with this:
                $(this).closest('.address')
                       .find('.results')
                       .html(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

You haven't shown how you rendered this partial, I guess you used AJAX again, so in the `success` callback of this AJAX call once you inject the partial into the DOM you invoke the `ajaxifyViewContactsLink` function.

Now your partial simply contains what it should contain - markup:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.AddressIndexViewModel
<table class="customers" style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 25%">
            Name
        </th>
        <th style="width: 25%">
            Actions
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
@foreach (Address item in Model.Addresses)
{
    <div class="address">
        <table style="width: 100%; border-top: none">
            <tr id="address-id-@item.AddressID">
                <td style="width: 25%; border-top: none">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%; border-top: none">
                    @Html.ActionLink(
                        "ContactsJQ", 
                        "CustomerAddressContacts", 
                        "Customer",
                        new { addressid = item.AddressID },
                        new { @class = "viewContacts" }
                    )
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="results"></div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That is pretty much working, however the `.closest().find()` in the ajax success doesn't work. I replaced it with just a div to test and that works. I have followed your changes to the view exactly so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, it seems to be working now! Just one small thing; the data in the ActionLink should be `new { addressid = item.AddressID }`, but otherwise it's perfect!

Comment: You are indeed correct, it should be `new { addressid = item.AddressID }`. Also I have removed the `data: { addressid: $(this).data(addressid) }` from the AJAX request as this is part of the url and not needed. I've also changed the HTTP verb to GET because this seems the more correct verb to use to fetch data from the server. Use POST when you are actually modifying some state on the server.

Comment: Ah yes, I have changed it to a GET rather than a POST too. Now I am going to go through my entire project and put all the scripts into seperate files (as you and others have pointed out it is a better practice), I've been putting it off for weeks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the

```
$(function(){
//code goes here
})
```

around the script. the page doesn't realise that there is jquery to be executed.

**EDIT**

you could use an eval on the script that is returned. like the following. kindof a hack i know but still should get you working.

```
    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                var $scripts = undefined;
                if ($(data).has('script'))
                {
                    $scripts = $(data).filter('script');
                }
                //APPEND YOUR HTML To the page. then run the scripts that are contained.

                if ($scripts != undefined)

                    $scripts.each(function ()
                    {
                        if ($(this).attr('src') != '' && $(this).attr('src'))
                            $.getScript($(this).attr('src'));
                        else
                            eval(this.innerHTML || this.innerText);
                    });

            };
```

this would be the success function of the ajax call

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't make any difference. I believe the script isn't even being returned with the partial view I posted.

Comment: @XN16 i have made an edit, it is the success function i use in some of my code which runs partial views

Answer (score 1):

In controller i have action .

```
public ActionResult ShowAllState()
        {
            return PartialView("_State", CityRepository.AllState);
        }
```

"_State" Is my partial view .

In view i have button . when i click on this button then my partial view lode all state data.

```
<h5>
    Page Lode With Jquery</h5>
<input type="button" value="Lode Form" id="btnLode" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnLode").click(function () {
            $("#LodeForm").load("/City/ShowAllState", function () {
                alert("Your page loaded Successfully !!!!!!!");
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="LodeForm">
</div>
```

i lode all my state data in "LodeForm" div .

i think this well help you....

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-attach the click handler to the newly loaded element everytime you reload the element over ajax.